# See last variable value after debugger finishes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

Is there an option to mark a variable so that the last value it had before debug execution finished is available to peek when writing code? Maybe through some VS extension? 
Sample scenario where it could be useful: complex JSON string that is obtained from REST API service that one needs to process but don't remember it's structure. Or and object deserialized to dynamic variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `Trace` for that. You can write anything to trace, and Visual Studio will pick it up during debugging (and it will keep the last run after debugging has finished).

No need to 'mark' a variable or anything fancy, just write a single line of code to do so.

(As a side note: if you are worried you might publish that code and write something security sensitive: you can omit `TRACE` from your build config for Release mode. All calls to `Trace` will be omitted from the eventual code.)

Comment: I'm already using Trace Points, but was thinking about something similar in functionality to Data Tips, so I could drill through structure of an object. But thanks, especially for the tip about exluding trace from release build.